# IE8 'Find': huge performance issues with large table when doctype declared

Tags: html, performance, internet-explorer-8, doctype

IE8 and below are having huge performance issues when it comes to searching a larger table (1000+ rows).

I set up a very simple test case that demonstrates this behavior. The pages are exactly the same, except one has an HTML5 doctype declared:

- [With Doctype](http://www.michaelsoutherton.com/temp/with_doctype.php)
- [Without Doctype](http://www.michaelsoutherton.com/temp/without_doctype.php)

(In IE, Ctrl+F and search for the ID: 1400)

Firefox, Safari, and Chrome don't have any problems finding any data in the table extremely quickly using the browser's native "Find" feature. IE9 (Win7) is slightly slower, but acceptable. IE8 (XP) stalls horribly and takes upwards of 10+ seconds to find something and locks up while it's processing.

I'm currently using an HTML5 doctype, and it validates with no errors. However, if I remove the doctype declaration, IE8 speeds up significantly. (Having no doctype messes up my site layout, so it's not an acceptable solution.)

Any suggestions? I unfortunately can't paginate this data - client needs all rows visible on one report on one webpage.

Comment: IE can and will switch rendering agents if it thinks it has to. The engines themselves behave very differently between 'standards' and 'quirks' mode. You may have to force IE into a particular mode to get your page to work acceptably.

Comment: I was afraid of that. It's a rather large web app built around standards mode, and switching to quirks mode breaks layout and causes some other strange JavaScript behaviors. Plus, downgrading my rendering agent just for IE's sake makes me want to vomit. Thankfully it's an internal app, so I can tell them to switch browsers if nothing else will help.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of not using the doctype.

Comment: @Rob: No purpose other than to demonstrate what I'm talking about. I would prefer to use a doctype to force it to render in standards mode, but IE8 slows down to a crawl on large tables when I do.

Comment: Modern web pages require a doctype so no getting around that. Can't answer the question but it is IE after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are performance issues with IE8 and heavy table usage. This is a browser issue and there is nothing to do with it. Maybe Microsoft can push out patch for it.